# Convert list of lists to list of integers

Tags: python, list

I need to convert a list of lists to a list of integers.

from:

```
L1 = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [3, 7, 1, 7], [0, 5, 6, 7], [9, 4, 5, 6]]
```

to:

```
L2 = [1234, 3717, 0567, 9456]
```

How can I make python recognize an integer starting with 0? Like the case `L2[2]`

The other question is, how can I check if items in a list are ordered?

```
A = [1, 2, 6, 9] ---->True
```

Other than this:

```
A == sorted(A)
```

You guys are FAST. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first question can be done by

```
L = [int("".join([str(y) for y in x])) for x in L]
```

Unfortunately, integers do not start with a 0.  There is no way to do this.

Checking if `A == sorted(A)` is a perfectly fine way to do this.

Comment: The list L, contains integers not strings. I tried your code. Your code would work for strings, but it still does not omit the commas.

Comment: >>> L1 = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [3, 7, 1, 7], [0, 5, 6, 7], [9, 4, 5, 6]]
>>> [int("".join([str(y) for y in x])) for x in L1]
[1234, 3717, 567, 9456]

Comment: No need for the inner brackets: `"".join(str(y) for y in x)`. Also, this is a case where `map` seems like a more natural fit: `"".join(map(str, x))`.

Comment: There is a reason for the inner brackets: it runs twice as quickly because it doesn't need to use slow generators.  I agree that `map` fits better, but it's apparently not supposed to be used anymore :/

Answer (score 4):

```
L2 = [reduce(lambda x,y : 10 * x + y, l) for l in L1]
```

If you want a solution that doesn't go through strings.

Answer (score 1):

For question 1, maybe Python 3 converts, but the plain .join give me a TypeError in Python 2. Try:

```
["".join(str(d) for d in x) for x in L]
```

...for the string representation, or

```
[int("".join(str(d) for d in x)) for x in L]
```

(The string representation is the only way to preserve leading zeros, except with formatted output...and then that's just string conversion on the way to the output file/string.)

For question 2: `all(A[i-1] < A[i] for i in range(1, len(A)))`

```
>>> A = [1, 2, 6, 9]
>>> all(A[i-1] < A[i] for i in range(1, len(A)))
True
```

Comment: You might as well use a list in the join as it will be faster (2x on my machine).

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I never timed that.  Does that apply to longer sequences, or do you think it's just the generator construction overhead on a 4-element list?

Comment: It may not apply to python 3.  I've found that if you are using it as a list, it's faster.  Testing on len(inputs) <= 100 million list comprehensions maintain a 2x speed improvement over generators.  I was unable to test any larger because it took to long.  Context switching for generators is slow in Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
L2 = [ int("1" + "".join(str(l) for l in ll1)) for ll1 in L1 ]
```

to keep the zeros and get:

```
[11234, 13717, 10567, 19456]
```

but then you need to get rid of the leftmost `1`s.